# Conventional prefix for "public" as the underscore is for "private"?

Tags: naming-conventions

First of all I'm aware what the _ is actually used for, it's just an easier way to frame the question :).

Just a curiosity if there ever was such a thing, and if so, what was it.

Answer (score 0):

The programming language Go, for instance, uses initial upper case for exported declarations and initial lower case for non-exported declarations.

Example:

```
func Product(x int, y int) int { //exported function
    return x * y
}

func sum(x int, y int) int { //non-exported function
    return x + y
}
```